# Canvas disappearing when polled by a4j:poll

Tags: html, jsf, canvas, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I need to show/hide a canvas element on a JSF page (RichFaces) based off of a boolean flag that would be received by polling the region the canvas is in. Everything works fine with the boolean (I have a `<h:output>` tag that displays this boolean to be sure), but the canvas disappears as soon as the region is polled.

I am limited to JSF 1.2, RichFaces 3, and Seam 2.2

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is this just a bug with the outdated versions?
2. Is there a work around that anyone knows?

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
<!--Code-->
<h:panelGrid id="imageRequested">
    <h:outputText id="imageRequestedValue" 
        value="#{sectionInteraction.imageRequested}"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="850" height="480" 
        style="border:2px solid black;user-select:none;
        -webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;
        display: #{(sectionInteraction.imageRequested) ? 'block' : 'none'}" />
</h:panelGrid>
<!--Code-->
<a:poll id="imageRequestedCheck" interval="1000" reRender="imageRequested"></a:poll>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "*but the canvas disappears as soon as the region is polled*." This means that the `<canvas>` is displayed as usual but disappears as soon as intervals from `<a:poll>` are concerned and never appears again?

Comment: Correct, I've been messing around with placement and other things for a while, but with no success.